# How to get new expectations using Tensorflow Times series CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have downloaded this code from [Rob Romijnders work on GitHub](https://github.com/RobRomijnders/CNN_tsc/blob/master/CNN_tsc_main.py), It shows how to train and evaluate times series data.

I tried to get new expectation using the trained models using this the following code:

```
 y_result = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,h_fc2) + b_fc2)
```

then I followed that with this code in anther part to predict the results:

```
result_classes = sess.run(y_result, feed_dict={x: flat_pixels,keep_prob: 1.0})
```

But the following error has come up :

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype bool
 [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_BOOL, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

The question is 
 **How to predict my new expectations? and why it error come up ? and how to solve this problem?**

I think it is a problem concerning how to dial with  [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/) API, framework, Trained model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is self explonatory - you did not provide **required** boolean value. For this code it is `bn_train` which denotes whether to train batch norm. Add it to your feed dict, just as it is passed in the code you are using.

The second part is that:

```
y_result = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,h_fc2) + b_fc2)
```

makes no sense, you are asking your model to multiply data (x) by final layer, what about all the previous ones?

Prediction should be possible by doing

```
prediction = tf.argmax(h_fc2,1)
```

and then after training

```
sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: flat_pixels,keep_prob: 1.0, bn_train: False})
```

Comment: also after adding value for {bn_train}, an error occur as follow [Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [109140,10], In[1]: [109140,5] ], problem is still found [How to predict new input].

Comment: see the updated answer

Comment: OK, It works. thanks @lejlot  . The  solution key was exactly `tf.argmax` function. it needs learning efforts.